# Read Soap Response with namespaces in Java 8

Tags: soap, java-8

I want to read AccountNumber,OrderNumber,responseCode and responseDescription.    I am able to read AccountNumber,OrderNumber using

```java
public static String getTagContents(String xmlString, String tagName) {
    String resp = "";
    String bTagName = "<" + tagName + ">";
    int stInd = xmlString.indexOf(bTagName);
    int enInd = xmlString.indexOf("</" + tagName + ">");
    if (stInd > -1 && enInd > -1) {
        resp = xmlString.substring(stInd + bTagName.length(), enInd);
    }
    return resp;
}
```

the same is failing for responseCode and responseDescription

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
   <env:Body>
      <eSAResponse xmlns="http://www.www.someurl.com/ESA">
         <eSAResponseData>
            <AccountNumber>45300895</AccountNumber>
            <OrderNumber />
         </eSAResponseData>
         <commonResponse>
            <responseCode xmlns="http://www.someurl.com">00</responseCode>
            <responseDescription xmlns="http://www.someurl.com/ESAASDmmonTypes">Success</responseDescription>
         </commonResponse>
      </eSAResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are looking for exact string value at tags. Code will work for AccountNumber because tag has not additional values. On the other hand, responseCode tag's exact string value like:

```
<responseCode xmlns="http://www.someurl.com">
```

I believe you should definitely use a common library like [DOMParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html)

If you really want to use your own code, this solution may be applied:

```
public static String getTagContents(String xmlString, String tagName) {
        String resp = "";
        String bTagName = "<" + tagName;
        int stInd = xmlString.indexOf(bTagName);
        int enInd = xmlString.indexOf("</" + tagName);
        if (stInd > -1 && enInd > -1) {
            resp = xmlString.substring(stInd + bTagName.length(), enInd);
        }
        return resp.split(">")[1];
    }
```